# Clean way to get function pointer from external std::function

Tags: c++

Because C, I need a **function pointer** from a **std::function** I receive at runtime.
Let's call *defineProxyCallback* the C function taking as input a function of *unsigned char*.
My hack to make this work has been :

```
struct callBacker {
    std::function<void(unsigned char)> normalKey;
};
callBacker cb = callBacker();
extern callBacker cb;
void proxy(unsigned char c) { cb.normalKey(c); };

void maincode {
    // Actually cb.normalKey is taken as an input from outside
    cb.normalKey = [](unsigned char c){std::cout << c << std::endl;} ;
    // this was just to lake the code work
    defineCallback(proxy);
}
```

defineCallback is defined somewhere else :

```
void defineCallback(void (*func)(unsigned char))
{
    *func("hello world");
    //should be : glutKeyboardFunc(func);
}
```

This works, but it's ugly AF. However, because the function pointer comes from a static function, I did not find any other way than using extern.

I've looked around but I've never found a solution for this exact problem. Any tip on making it cleaner ?

Thank you very much !

For clarity : I **cannot change** the fact that I need to provide a function pointer to defineCallback, nor that I receive a std::function from outside.

Comment: why do you use std::function and not a plain function pointer?

Comment: Why do you need `struct callBacker`? Why not just a global `std::function`? It's tricky. I suppose you could use `thread_local` to add some thread safety.

Comment: Can you please provide some [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), running code? How is `defineCallback()` defined? Your code looks like you added many layers of wrapping to make an original problem work, that you should include in the question.

Comment: I've provided an example of defineCallback in the querstion now. The constraints are :  
(1) defineCallback takes as input a function pointer. 
(2) My code recieves a std::function. 

I cannot escape any of these two constraints.

Comment: I guess the syntax is `(*func)(...);`, not `&func(...);` or `*func(...);`.

Comment: That is a bad way to define a callback. In C a callback should always have a `void *priv` for the user to store arbitrary data to pass to the callback. Once you have that you can pass a struct containing the std::function and use a simple function pointer to extract it from priv and call it.

Comment: Probably is, unfortunately little I can do about it :)

Comment: Do you receive one std::function pointer or several? If you get several, you could create a templated proxy function or a templated class with a static proxy member function. You would instantiate the (enough) templates at compiletime. You could keep them stored in an array, until the need arrives.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think this is ever going to be super-neat and tidy. If it were me I would probably use `inline` functions so that they could go in a *header file* and I would use `thread_local`storage to add a little thread safety.

Something a bit like this:

```
// force the compiler to make sure only one of these functions
// is linked and this can go in the header file
inline std::function<void(unsigned char)>& get_std_function()
{
    // returns a different object for each thread that calls it
    static thread_local std::function<void(unsigned char)> fn;
    return fn;
}

inline void proxy(unsigned char c){ get_std_function()(c); };

void maincode() {
    // Actually cb.normalKey is taken as an input from outside
    get_std_function() = [](unsigned char c){std::cout << c << std::endl;} ;

    // this was just to lake the code work
    defineCallback(proxy);
}
```